# When WP_Query only returns 1 post, how do I automatically redirect to that post?

Tags: posts, wp-query, permalinks, redirect

I've been searching around for a few hours now and can't figure out how to do this. Seems really simple. I've seen lots of redundant examples on how to redirect to a single post when a search result returns only one post, but what if I set up a custom WP_query to only show posts by a custom field/metabox value and if there is only one post with that value--redirect to that post? So far I have a custom WP_Query set up on a page template which does what I want it do but I can't figure out the conditional redirect part:

```
<?php
$rawfiltertag = get_post_meta($post->ID, '_cmb_client_name', true);
$filtertag = sanitize_title( $rawfiltertag );
// WP_Query arguments
$args = array (
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'meta_query' => array(
        array(
            'key' => '_cmb_client_target',
            'value' => $rawfiltertag
        )
    )
);
// The Query
$the_query = new WP_Query( $args );
if ($the_query->post_count == 1) {
    wp_redirect( get_permalink( $the_query->posts['0']->ID ) );
}   
?>
```

Right now this does nothing on the page I am trying to set it up on.

Comment: Here is a short tutorial for what you are looking for: http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/auto-redirect-when-wordpress-search-query-only-returns-one-match/

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by checking the number of results returned by your query. Try this.

```
<?php

    $rawfiltertag = get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_cmb_client_name', true );
    $filtertag = sanitize_title( $rawfiltertag );

    // wp_query arguments
    $args = array (
        'post_type' => 'post',
        'meta_query' => array(
            array(
                'key' => '_cmb_client_target',
                'value' => $rawfiltertag
            )
        )
    );

    // the query
    $the_query = new WP_Query( $args );

    if ( $the_query->post_count == 1 && $the_query->max_num_pages == 1 ) {
        wp_redirect( get_permalink( $the_query->posts['0']->ID ) );
        exit;
    }

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you only have to change `'0'`, that is a string, by simply `0`, that is a integer corresponding to the first place of the array of posts.

I thik this is a good idea, maybe WordPress should do it by default ^^